# Finding the derivative with functions inside, such as $g(x) = \dfrac{3x-1}{f(x)}$

Tags: calculus, functions

With a question such as:

$$g(x) = \dfrac{3x-1}{f(x)}$$

How does one approach finding the derivative, could the Chain Rule be used?

The book, gives the answer as:
$g'(x) =\dfrac {3f(x)-(3x+1)f'(x) }{ (f(x))^2}$

Though I don't understand how to get to it.

Comment: Yeah. That seems pretty fine.

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask, how do you find the solution.

Comment: What do you need to find exactly? Solution to what?

Comment: How to find the derivative of g(x), for example, how to use the Chain Rule to get the solution. Edit: cleared up the post

Answer (score 1):

You have $g(x)=\dfrac{3x-1}{f(x)}$, treat $3x-1=p(x)$, just another function.

Now the derivative of $\dfrac{p(x)}{f(x)}= \dfrac{p'(x)f(x)-f'(x)p(x)}{(f(x))^2}$ which is nothing but $g'(x)$. And yeah, this is [Quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) as Michalis says.

Comment: Just a small addition: The rule is called quotient rule: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule
It follows from the product and chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

is not a CHAIN RULE is just the derivative of a quotient

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g(x)^{2}}$$